# how to change ASP.NET Configuration tool connection string

Tags: asp.net, string, configuration, connection

how can I change ASP.NET Configuration tool-s connection string name? 
(Which connection string will ASP.NET Configuration tool will use)
I'm learning ASP.NET and everywhere and in book that I'm reading now theres connection string named: LocalSqlServer.

I want to use my local sql server database instead of sql express to store Roles, Membership and other data.

I have used aspnet_regsql.exe to create needed data structures in my database. after that I changed my web.config to look like:

`<connectionStrings>
      <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(LOCAL); Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

but when I run ASP.NET Configuration tool it says that:
"The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty."

ASP.NET Configuration tool uses connection string named: ApplicationServices not LocalSqlServer.

cause of that I have to modify web.config to:
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=(LOCAL); Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

and everything works fine.

I wish to know why the hell my web site uses connection string named: ApplicationServices and all books and online documentations uses LocalSqlServer? and how to change it to LocalSqlServer?

I have:
Windows 7
Sql Server 2008 R2
Visual Studio 2010 Premium
Project type is website

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

accidentally I have found my question answer when looking to web.config file.

if you override default machine.config configuration settings in web.config file you can change ASP.NET Configuration tool-s connection string name.

I got my web.config file from book-s code archive and it was the problem.

in web.config u can override which connection string name will be used for: membership, profile and roleManager.

to override membership use:
`<membership>

      <providers>

        <clear/>

        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"

             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

             enablePasswordReset="true"

             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"

             requiresUniqueEmail="false"

             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"

             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"

             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"

             passwordAttemptWindow="10"

             applicationName="/"/>

      </providers>

    </membership>`

where **connectionStringName** is the name of connection string which will be used for storing membership data.

others are:

`<profile>

      <providers>

        <clear/>

        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"

             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"

             connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"

             applicationName="/"/>

      </providers>

</profile>`

and

`<roleManager enabled="true">

      <providers>

        <clear />

        <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/"

          name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />

        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"

          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />

      </providers>

</roleManager>`